# Configuring Internet Access on Ubuntu v18.04

Tags: server, internet, static-ip, ip-address

All,

To enable static IP, I had to update /etc/network/interfaces file and make the necessary changes in my ***Ubuntu v18.04 VM*** for the **eth0** vitual ethernet card. I added the **static IP** of ***192.168.56.101*** where as the dynamic IP was in the range of 172.17.X.X.

Ever since I changed to static, the internet connection is **not** working. I know a lot more needs to be done for it to work but I dont know what. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
rgn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed ***[this link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04/#:%7E:text=Configuring%20Static%20IP%20address%20on%20Ubuntu%20Desktop,-Setting%20up%20a&text=Click%20on%20the%20cog%20icon,on%20the%20%E2%80%9CApply%E2%80%9D%20button.)*** and got the Static IP working as well as Internet.

Answer (score 0):

How did you choose the static IP that you set?

If your computer is not in the same subnet as the other machines on your network, it would not be able to communicate with them without a router in between.

Unless you have some unusual subnet masks, you'll need an IP in the 172.17.X.X range, but you'll have to make sure you don't take an IP that is being given out dynamically to something else.

A good resource for learning more about subnets can be found at https://www.cbtnuggets.com/blog/technology/networking/networking-basics-what-is-ipv4-subnetting